# ExpressJS and RethinkDb Tutorial Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, rethinkdb

Very new to Db and JS and trying to learn ExpressJS, RethinkDb using a tutorial from this link.

https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb-example-nodejs-chat

I followed the instructions and hitting an error in basic module loading I suppose. Looks like some dependency problem or I'm probably missing some step.

As specified in the instruction, I have successfully setup rethinkDb and can see the DB explorer in

http://localhost:8080

But when `node app` is executed as specified in instructions, I"m hitting an error below. Any help in this regard please?

```
/Users/test/rethinkdb-example-nodejs-chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/store.js:35
Store.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/test/rethinkdb-example-nodejs-chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/store.js:35:42)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/test/rethinkdb-example-nodejs-chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:16:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
```

Comment: Hi, did you do npm install?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

process.EventEmitter was deprecated and not working in new node version. This has been answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1158237/error-starting-node-js-localserver-undefined-eventemitter-prototype)

Can you rollback to older node.js version and see if you could run the tutorial

https://github.com/LearnBoost/websocket.io/issues/55

Comment: Wow ! That fixed the problem, But I had to go as old as 5.12. Are there other tutorials which work and are easy ones for beginners?

Comment: Glad it helped, most of the rethinkdb tutorials are at least 4-5 years, this is the one I found to be latest, though it stress on creating rest api with rethinkdb and express, it could give you a good start. https://medium.com/@brucelim/creating-a-rest-api-with-rethinkdb-nodejs-express-81ed12f01e59